# How do I add COUNT(foo.bar) to a dynamic query?

Tags: database

I have a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT t.tid, t.name, t.description, COUNT(i.nid) 
  FROM taxonomy_term_data t 
  LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index AS i ON i.tid = t.tid
  GROUP BY i.nid 
  LIMIT 60
```

I wish to write this as a [dynamic query](http://drupal.org/node/310075).

This is what I come up with, but it fails on the `COUNT()` part.

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
$query->addField('t', 'tid');
$query->addField('t', 'name');
$query->addField('t', 'description');
$query->addField('COUNT(i.nid)', 'count');
$query->leftjoin('taxonomy_index', 'i', 'i.nid = t.nid');
$query->range(0, 60)->groupBy('i.nid');
```

The string representation of the query is:

```sql
SELECT t.tid AS tid, t.name AS name, t.description AS description, COUNTi.nid.count AS count FROM {taxonomy_term_data} t LEFT OUTER JOIN {taxonomy_index} i ON i.nid = t.nid GROUP BY i.nid LIMIT 60 OFFSET 0
```

`COUNTi.nid.count AS count` is obviously wrong.

How do I add `COUNT(foo.bar)` to a dynamic query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you need to use the `addExpression` method instead:

`$query->addExpression('COUNT(i.nid)', 'count');`

Also, I believe you need to call this method after the `leftJoin` for the `taxonomy_index` table to be in object scope.

See here for an example:
https://drupal.org/node/1848358

Answer (score 5):

@[MEsch](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1598/mesch) is right about the method to call, but I would rather write the code as the following.

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name', 'description'));

$alias = $query->leftjoin('taxonomy_index', 'i', '%alias.nid = t.nid');

$query->addExpression("COUNT($alias.nid)", 'count');
$query->range(0, 60)->groupBy("$alias.nid");
```

[SelectQuery::leftJoin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::leftJoin/7) returns the alias effectively used in the query, and the code I wrote is more generic.

As for calling `SelectQuery::addExpression()` before `SelectQuery::leftJoin()`, the result doesn't change, if you are not using the alias returned from `SelectQuery::leftJoin()`. The following queries return both the same result.

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name', 'description'));
$query->leftjoin('taxonomy_index', 'i', 'i.nid = t.nid');
$query->addExpression("COUNT(i.nid)", 'count');
$query->range(0, 60)->groupBy("i.nid");
```

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name', 'description'));
$query->addExpression("COUNT(i.nid)", 'count');
$query->leftjoin('taxonomy_index', 'i', 'i.nid = t.nid');
$query->range(0, 60)->groupBy("i.nid");
```

When you print `$query`, you get the following, in both the cases.

```sql
SELECT t.tid AS tid, t.name AS name, t.description AS description, COUNT(i.nid) AS count
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_data} t
LEFT OUTER JOIN {taxonomy_index} i ON i.nid = t.nid
GROUP BY i.nid
LIMIT 60 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: That's fair, and it is what I would have done myself. I wrote my answer because I could not use a comment to write what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno for the more complete answer, and the clarification/correction around my second point.

Comment: I got to know the usage of `%alias` and `$alias` from this answer.